# Jest testing ComponentDidMount's axios

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, axios

I am trying to write a Jest test for an axios request.
The axios request is inside the componentDidMount lifecycle method and I do not know how to get it.

React:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        axios
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(res => res.data)
            .catch(err => 'catch error')
    }

    render() {
        return (null);
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Test:

```
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent';

test('Axios is working', () => {
  return MyComponent.prototype.componentDidMount().then(data => {
    expect(data).toBeDefined;
  });
});
```

While testing I get error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

So the

> MyComponent.prototype.componentDidMount()

is not working.

So my final question is -  **How can you define componentDidMount** to **test the axios request in it**?

Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: componentDidMount does not return a `Promise<T>` you simply cannot execute `then()` against it. Usually you would mock the axios request with something like [jest-mock-axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios) then check that expected result, like state on the component instance has been updated. Also you wouldn't target the `prototype`, you would test an instance of `MyComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

`index.tsx`:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  public async componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(res => res.data)
      .catch(err => 'catch error');
  }

  public render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Unit test:

```
import MyComponent from './';
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

axios.get = jest.fn();

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  describe('test with jestjs', () => {
    it('componentDidMount - 1', async () => {
      (axios.get as jest.MockedFunction<typeof axios.get>).mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: 'mocked data' });
      await MyComponent.prototype.componentDidMount();
      expect(axios.get).toBeCalledWith('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    });

    it('componentDidMount - 2', async () => {
      (axios.get as jest.MockedFunction<typeof axios.get>).mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('some error'));
      const actualValue = await MyComponent.prototype.componentDidMount();
      expect(axios.get).toBeCalledWith('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    });

    it('render', () => {
      expect(MyComponent.prototype.render()).toEqual(null);
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/54794512/index.spec.tsx
  MyComponent
    test with jestjs
      ✓ componentDidMount - 1 (6ms)
      ✓ componentDidMount - 2 (1ms)
      ✓ render (1ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.073s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/54794512